# How can I read data from a Google Sheets cell in my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have a local webpage, `index.html`, where an HTML element with `id="test"` is supposed to display the content of one particular cell, A3 ("10") for example, from [this Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kFFysrHSapJXr-DxdYbuaMzkg5iBP60jR6OBFgzwSds/edit?usp=sharing).

I published it in the form of a webpage, but I'm not 100% sure if it's the best form for what I'm planning to do.

How can I display a selected cell from a Google Spreadsheet in the element specified above using JavaScript?

I can't rely on PHP because I want to put the `index.html` file on my computer and a cellphone without actually hosting them.

Based on Matthew Lock's answer, I've linked to tabletop.js, which is sitting in my JS folder. This folder is on the same level as the index file.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/tabletop.js"></script>
```

then, inside the main script tag for the JS, I've included:

```
function init() {
     Tabletop.init( { key: '1kFFysrHSapJXr-DxdYbuaMzkg5iBP60jR6OBFgzwSds',
               callback: function(data, tabletop) { window.alert("data") },
               simpleSheet: true } )
    };
```

to see if it spits out anything. Which it doesn't. Not even with the simple "data" alert. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a minimal example I'm trying to build in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkyo8a81/13/), but I think I'm running into other issues there with how I linked to tabletop.js (under external resources)...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you have tried so far. Without this example *in your question*, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I added more steps, based on a kind first answer. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Could we have a link to your webpage to see if there's any error messages in the browser's error console, or could you construct a jsfiddle of your page?

Comment: @NilsSens Your question still does not include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure your example is **complete** and **verifiable**. The code in your question needs to reproduce the issue.

Comment: ok will add a simple version of what I'm trying to build. sorry!

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/rkyo8a81/16/)

Comment: Hm, In my browser I'm not getting the alert...

Comment: I've simplified and got it working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/rkyo8a81/21/ I think the documentation is a little wrong about the key, it seems it should just be the key part of the url, not the whole url.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much! It still didn't fire the alert in JSfiddle, but I think that's because of the tabletop.js that's not working there. In my own browser it WORKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read a Google Docs/Drive cell from your own web page using javascript I recommend the [Tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() { init() };

  var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AmYzu_s7QHsmdDNZUzRlYldnWTZCLXdrMXlYQzVxSFE&output=html';

  function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                     callback: showInfo,
                     simpleSheet: true } )
  }

  function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    alert("Successfully processed!")
    console.log(data);
  }
</script>
```

The data parameter of the showInfo function will contain an array objects. Each row of the array corresponds to a row in the spreadsheet, and the cells will be in an object with each column header as the name. E.g.:

```
[ { name: "Carrot", category: "Vegetable", healthiness: "Adequate" }, 
  { name: "Pork Shoulder", category: "Meat", healthiness: "Questionable" }, 
  { name: "Bubblegum", category: "Candy", healthiness: "Super High"} ]
```

**Note** at time of writing the documentation appears to be incorrect. The key parameter just needs the key value from the public spreadsheet url, not the entire url.

Comment: Thank you!! this looks like it's going to help me make it happen!

Only question, where / how would I refer to the particular cell (A1)? I'm new to JS.

Comment: ha! I just read this bit as well. So I'm assuming that I can call an INDEX of this array as usual? :)

data[0] would give me the entire first row as a simple array, and I could store that in a var to again only access the first cell?

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to implement it but the JS isn't working. I'll edit my orig. question. :)

Comment: One last question... I'm only seeing "[object Object],[object Object]" in the alert. Is that because the function used is showinfo?

Comment: Javascript alerts only show strings, and the string casting of an array of objects is just "[object Object],[object Object]". If you want to see the contents of the object for debugging use console.log(data); and look in the browser's console: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

This question has aged. The working approach on my page is now this:

```
const spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxYourSheetIdxxxxxx'
fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json`)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(text => {
    
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(text.substr(47).slice(0, -2)).table.rows
    return jsonObj
    // I'm cutting off the first two rows (I think the letters A-Z and the categories) to get only clean table data

})
.then(json => {
    // console.dir(json) // see the returned JSON
    json.forEach(element => 
    {    
        // console.dir(element.c)  
        // Append to my own frontend 'events' collection:
        events.push(element.c)
    })
})
```

Hope it helps anyone. It's a hacky tool. There are serious security implications as in my case, the writeable G-Sheet is visible on the front end. Some of this should be moved backstage. Anyways, it's a small project and if anyone ever wanted to sabotage a local art school, I have the content ready for backup. It was born out of my incompetence with DB & will be replaced with something more solid, soon.